# populate php form fields with mysql array (on click)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm a php/mysql newbie, working on an invoicing application. I have a summary.php page, in which I'm using php to query a db and render a table with the retrieved data:

```
< ?php
    mysql_connect ... [ snip ] ...

    // retrieve all data in the 'Invoices' table ...
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Invoices") or die(mysql_error());
    // ... and store each record in a variable:
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

and my table is:

```
<table class="record-summary">
    <form action="/edit.php" method="post">
    <tr>
        <th ... 
        [ snip: more table headers ] ...

<?php
    $controls = "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"details.php\" /><input type=\"submit\" value=\"edit.php\" />";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td class=\"id\">". $row['ID']. "</td>";
            echo "<td class=\"inv\">". $row['invoiceNumber']. "</td>";
            [ snip: more data cells ] ...
            echo "<td class=\"controls\">". $controls . "</td>";
```

The last cell (td.controls) in each row contains two submits, one linking to a detail view (details.php), the other to a form page (edit.php). My objective is to populate either page with the values of the record/row. Where I need help is how exactly to use the $row variable to carry this array to e.g., edit.php, and populate the fields in the form (actually I'm fairly certain I have the syntax for the form inputs' value attributes). Both details.php and edit.php have *all* the data fields in the record represented, though in summary.php only a portion of the fields are displayed (ergo, 'summary.php'). So my questions are:

How do I ensure that when either button is clicked, the $row contains the values of the given record, and how to push the array into either details.php or edit.php?

Many thanks in advance,

src

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the ID to `edit.php` and `details.php` but without the form just with two links to `edit.php?id=`and `details.php?id=`:

```
<?php
    // $controls = "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"details.php\" /><input type=\"submit\" value=\"edit.php\" />"; <-- is not necessary
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class=\"id\"><a href=\"details.php?id=". $row['ID']. "\">details.php</a> | <a href=\"edit.php?id=". $row['ID']. "\">edit.php</a></td>";
        echo "<td class=\"inv\">". $row['invoiceNumber']. "</td>";
        // [ snip: more data cells ] ...
        // echo "<td class=\"controls\">". $controls . "</td>"; <-- is not necessary
```

You can grab the data using the id:

```
//....
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
else
{
    die("There is no id.");
}

$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Invoices WHERE id = %s", $id);
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: Thx tttony. I like this, for one thing it seems somewhat more semantic to use links for my purpose rather than a form. However can you please add to this how I access the $row data in details.php or is the idea here to grab only the ID and then re-query the db on load of details.php/edit.php?? Thx!

Comment: Thx again tttony. Took me a while to notice that I had non-matching cases in my anchors and $_GET. P.s. for the benefit of others, please add the missing semicolon at the end of your 'die' statement :) ... (I don't have edit privileges)

Comment: Btw, while this solution makes sense to me (and I'll proceed today with populating my form pages), I'm still wondering if there's any advantage of passing instead the array (all the row's data) from one page to the other, rather than re-querying the db, and in any case, how to do so. I'm off to read up on the rest of your solution (ie.., sprintf, etc.) ... many thanks again

Comment: you can use a form but it will not be one form it will be one form for each row, using `<input name="invoiceNumber" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['invoiceNumber'] ?>" />` to store each row and the edit/details pages will grab the data using e.g: `$_POST['invoiceNumber']` but is not a recommended way

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"row\" value=\"" . $row . "\"/>";
```

Include this in your loop and your form's "action" script will be able to access the corresponding `$row` variable via `$_POST['row']`.

Comment: Thanks but I'm a little lost. I added the hidden field to $controls, and tried echoing $_POST['row'] (and $row and $result) in details.php but I was guessing. I'm trying to get the row data available to details.php. Can you please elaborate? Thx